# How to hide output of first command when using the || operator and exit?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, error-handling, redirect

This hides output from the first command, and prints `Oops` to stderr if it fails. So far, so good.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
invalid_command > /dev/null 2>&1 || >&2 echo "Oops"
echo hi
```

That outputs this:

```
Oops
hi
```

---

But I need to exit as well as  printing a message if the first command failed. So I tried using parenthesis.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
invalid_command > /dev/null 2>&1 || ( >&2 echo "Oops" ; exit )
echo hi
```

Here's the output of that:

```
Oops
hi
```

But now the `exit` doesn't work because it's doing it in a subshell, causing it to print `hi`, even though I wanted the script to exit.

So, how do I get Bash to `echo` some text and exit if a specific command failed using the `||` operator? I'm aware that I can use an `if` one-liner to do that, but I'd prefer to not have to use a full `if` statement if I can avoid it.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ "$(invalid_command > /dev/null 2>&1 ; printf $?)" != "0" ]; then >&2 echo 'Oops' ; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: The `[` is a command that evaluates an expression and sets its own exit code appropriately, which is then consumed by the `if` statement. You can also write `if ! invalid_command >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo >&2 Oops; exit; fi`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) (notice the `;` on the end of `exit`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
invalid_command > /dev/null 2>&1 || { >&2 echo "Oops" ; exit; }
echo hi
```

Return this on my terminal.

```
$ ./test.sh 
Oops
```

If you have a lot command, you can trap all errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
on_error() {
    >&2 echo "Oops"
    exit 1
}
trap 'on_error' ERR
invalid_command > /dev/null 2>&1
echo hi
```

This will print **Oops** and exit immediately, if any command on the script is failing.